# Why I was banned for a week for one not clear audit?

Tags: discussion, support, disputed-review-audits, ban

Here is the [audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/7247402) (low-quality one):

[image: screenshot]

However I can not longer learn from it, as it's empty. It was simple sentence answering the question, definitely not a spam.

Sometimes people does that, e.g.

[image]

How how possible that one post banned me for one week? For over last 10 audits I did correct answers and I never had situation that 1 wrong audit for 10 did ban me for over 1 week. I think somebody did that for no reason thinking I was bot?

Comment: One failed audit will never result in a ban.  You would have had to have failed quite a few audits.  Also, link to the audit, don't screenshot it.

Comment: @Servy Added link.

Comment: It's spam, you marked it as okay, you shouldn't have, I fail to see what the problem is here.

Comment: @Servy It didn't contain any spam links. I don't remember the content of it, so how do I know if it was a spam (how can I check it)? I'm pretty sure I haven't failed audits for quite long, maybe 2 in last few days. How do I check my total audit fails?

Comment: It was an account created solely to advertise a product, and didn't include a link to try to subvert the spam filters.  And if you're failing several audits every few days then I'm not surprised in the least that you're banned.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This was the answer, which *was* visible to you when you first reviewed:

[image]

I think, if you try really hard, you can probably figure out why that wasn't an answer to the question. If it helps, this product's backers are notorious spammers who've plagued multiple sites on Stack Exchange for *years* now.

You've been banned 8 times from review so far, and failed *many* more audits in between bans. Your previous ban was for failing to identify this bit of spam:

[image]

You appear to have a problem with reviewing these answers in context. Please, if you decide to review again, put a little bit of thought into what you're doing.

Comment: 'Long Path Tool' wording was familiar for me from graphics design perspective, so I thought maybe there is a tool like that, so how would I know this tool doesn't exist for specific problem? It was not obvious spam (without Googling it wouldn't be possible to know).

Comment: The Hebrew one I've failed, because I was trying to edit that to correct the links (and it failed straight away), because I've checked that website before (going to it) and was looking on-topic and it was not spam in my opinion either as it was related to the question about module for Hebrew characters, e-commerce or something similar. People on Drupal SE pasting links to the modules, commerce solutions all the time and it's something normal.

Comment: Even if you didn't know it's spam, how does that "look ok"?

Comment: @kenorb If you think that posting spam is "normal" then clearly the ban was very important.  It would seem that you just aren't up to the task of reviewing content if you consider spam to be acceptable.

Comment: [Long Path Tool](http://longpathtool.com/) actually is a tool for renaming files, so it answers the question correctly, the same as tools which you're installing from the external packages (e.g. `rename`), what's the difference? It could be the comment instead, but definitely not spam for me, as spam should be not related to the question at all. However the answer could be more expanded and having some introduction text what this software does.

Comment: @kenorb If you are going to justify spam posts like that, it makes all the sense in the world for you to be banned from reviewing.

Comment: So what's the difference between answer: 'You can install `rename` tool via `brew install rename` or compile manually by downloading from [link](http://plasmasturm.org/code/rename/)', vs. 'You can install "[Long Path Tool](http://longpathtool.com/)" for Windows and it's designed for renaming long paths.' ? Which seems to be for free, which I've downloaded it to check that it does what it says. It's determined if the software is free of charge, open source or commercial one? If the product is commercial, then it's spam?

Comment: If the spam is defined as removing any 1-2 sentence answer with any tool/soft name in it (even if answers the question), then I'm fine with that. Just asking for the clarification of spam in this case. Then at the same time all 1-2 sentence long answers on Drupal SE pointing to the right modules solving the questions are spams as well.

Comment: @kenorb _"I thought **maybe**..."_ -- FWIW when I review, anytime I notice myself thinking "maybe...", I press skip. [There is no shame in using “Skip”](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252195/839601), really